# Any tricks to export Go docs to be served statically?

Tags: documentation, go

I'd like to use docs generated by godoc to be served statically (on App Engine) for a project I created. I see that godoc starts a server and apparently the package docs are all generated dynamically. But is there a workaround to save the docs to the filesystem or what other options do I have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using GitHub, there's a pretty nice project for this already: http://gopkgdoc.appspot.com/

Documentation's at the bottom of the page. It's open source and with a little effort, you may be able to get it to generate documentation from non-GitHub services.